# Django Fake Primary Key

Tags: mysql, django

I have a legacy database which I have no control over and I am trying to create a model for it in Django. It has a composite primary key and I do not wish to create dirty hacks to achieve it in Django. What are the consequences of just specifying one of the field as primary key even if it is not unique.

I only need to do some simple reading of the data. No writing is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not going to be doing any writing, I will completely ignore the problems that writing present.

However, the problem of reading will probably manifest itself as one of the following:

- Linked models (ForeignKey and ManyToManyField) will fail on lookup if the `primary_key` you've specified is not unique
- `Model.objects.get(pk=N)` will fail with `MultipleObjectsReturned` if you try the lookup with the primary key
- Some facets of admin may not work correctly (the detail views for instance) if the primary key you've specified is not unique

There are probably others I haven't thought of.

Consider using something like [django-compositekey](https://github.com/simone/django-compositekey) that may handle problems with trying to work around standard django behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up using raw sql since it is a rarely performed function and quite decoupled from my main app anyway.